# Why broadcast receiver is not executing BOOT_COMPLETED and not displaying toast message?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

- I am trying a simple example with broadcast receiver registered with action BOOT_COMPLETED... but, application is not giving toast message... I searched a lot.. tried both the ways of registering receiver in manifest.xml and in java code also... but I really don't know what is the problem in it...
- please help me to sort out this issue as i need to start service on boot up..
- thanks in advance..

1) Activity class

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Boot is completed..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

2) manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bootupservicedemoagain"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="com.example.bootupservicedemoagain.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have also tried this in activity class `onReceive` method but same outcome!

```
if(intent.getAction() != null) 
{
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Boot is completed..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try action permission `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` to your intent filter. It solved the same problem for me. Your receiver declaration in manifest file should look like this:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.bootupservicedemoagain.BootReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Also, category `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />` is not needed.

Comment: same output... no message displayed

Comment: which device you have? I have tried on Samsung, htc, micromax tab, emulator also.. but same output

Comment: LG Optimus G, Galaxy Tab 2 10.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the difference between my registration and your registration of your boot receiver is the category in the manifest.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Consider removing that line and try again.

**Edit with my code**

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        /**
         * The onReceive method is a default method which is called when the broadcast
         * receiver is registered and the intent with the action below is sent.
         * This action will start the service. ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is defined in the 
         * AndroidManifest.xml.
         */
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(myIntent);
        }

    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<!-- Handling for On Boot Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name="path.to.OnBootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- End Handling for On Boot Receiver -->

<service
    android:name="path.to.service"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>
```

Comment: which device you have? I have tried on Samsung, htc, micromax tab, emulator also.. but same output

Comment: Nexus 5, and Moto G and a HTC Desire HD with a custom rom. Also I just realized, if you don't have a context in the broadcastreceiver, it's kinda hard to send a toast message. Show the toast message in the service and try again. You probably have the applicationcontext and cannot show a toast message.

Comment: not worked... I really don't understand where is the problem? as all codes are correct.. help is appreciated.. thnks

Comment: When I was debugging this, I used the service to display the toast messages, not the broadcastreceiver. Every time I would start the phone, I'd get spammed with post messages of all the lifecycle methods (oncreate etc.).

Comment: I also noticed that you don't have your service in your manifest. See my edit.

Comment: I am worked on broadcast receiver many times from last one year, but never come across BOOT_COMPLETED action... I really don't understand where the problem is..

Comment: Are you sure you have defined the service in your manifest? It can't find the service if you don't have it in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Well The Following combination works for me :
at the Manifest File

```
        <!-- Get Boot Action -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.try.BootBroadcast"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="MintBootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
```

and for the JAVA Broadcast is as you did

```
public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Strings - Log
final String TAG = "BootBroadCast";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context mBootCtx, Intent mBootIntent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "BootBroadCast BroadcastReceiver +++STARTED+++");
    Log.d(TAG, "@Boot actionCaught :" + mBootIntent.getAction());
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(mBootIntent
                .getAction())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "@Boot actionCaught :" + mBootIntent.getAction());
            // Now you are getting your Boot reciever
        }
    Log.i(TAG, "BootBroadCast BroadcastReceiver ---END/FIN---");
}
```

Please tell me if that helped .

Comment: Why we need `android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky when I tested it, it was device based, some devices (Manufactures) listened to the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED while others BOOT_COMPLETED

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes there is problem with full path to reciever. Try relative

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Project wouldn't compile if the path wasn't correct.